# Is it possible to achieve a shorter time than O (n) to insert, delete and similar operations in a n-ary tree?

Tags: java, tree, time-complexity

I have in the university to implement a n-ary tree and to insert a node as the child of another the complexity is O (n) since I have to go through it and look for the father to insert it, and since it is not organized (like the BST) I have no way to reduce the search. My question is: Is it possible to achieve a shorter time than O (n) to insert, delete, obtain a parent and similar operations in a n-ary tree?

Comment: "since it is not organized" You'd have to organise it.

Comment: If you're not using the tree to optimize searches, then what's it for?

Comment: I am using the tree for business hierarchies. That is, the direction, sub-direction are subordinated, then each of the departments and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you know the parent, as you mentioned, the complexity is O(1) since you only have to add it to the list of children.

O(n) yields if you want to put a node into your "stupid" *tree* (the tree, not you), and O(log(n)) for a BST.

But there a mutliple variants to reduce complexity for one function at cost of another, depending on your needs and the data, too.